# I'm only getting the latest date as dataframe, rather than all...?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the below code to scrape several tables across multiple dates. The code works well, but the output when saving to CSV only stores the latest data as a dataframe.

What am I missing here in order to union / concatenate all these scraped dates into one dataframe?

```
##### import packages #######
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import re
#############################

years = ["2023"]
weeks = list(range(1, 5)) # Weeks should probably range from 1 to 53, since rarely there can be 53 instead of 52 weeks in a year

urls = [f"https://www.debestseller60.nl/{year}{week:02}#top" for year in years for week in weeks]

### set user-agent #### 
## response = requests.get(url,headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        # Your scraping logic here
        data = []

        cards = soup.find_all("div", class_="card")

        for book in cards:
            author = book.find("div", class_="card__author").text.strip() if book.find("div", class_="card__author") else None
            title = book.find("div", class_="card__title heading-2 mb-2 clickable").text.strip() if book.find("div", class_="card__title heading-2 mb-2 clickable") else None 
            Hebban_link = book.find("y-use", class_="History").text.strip() if book.find("y-use", class_="History") else None 
            for card in cards:
                tags_div = card.find('div', class_='card__tags')
                if tags_div is not None:
                    tags = tags_div.find_all('div', class_='card__tags__tag')
                    if len(tags) >= 4:
                        tag = tags[-2].text.strip()
                    else:
                        tag = tags[-1].text.strip()
                else:
                    tag = "No tags found for this card"

            # find the div element with the class "weeks__week week week--active"
            active_week_div = soup.find('div', class_='weeks__week week week--active')

            # print the text content of the div element
            print(active_week_div.text.strip())

            #append data
            data.append({"Author": author, "Title": title, "Hebban_link": Hebban_link,"ISBN": tag, "week_year":active_week_div.text.strip()})

            #convert to dataframe
            df = pd.DataFrame(data)

            ## add rank
            df["rank"] = df.index + 1

            print(df)


            data.append(df)

else:
                print(f"Failed to fetch data for URL: {url}")

#converted a file to csv
pd.concat(data).to_csv("top60.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting `df` at each iteration of your loop.

You should [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) `df` to a list at each iteration:

```
dfs = []
for url in urls:
        # ...
        data = []
        for book in cards:
            # ...
            data.append({"Author": author, "Title": title, "Hebban_link": Hebban_link,"ISBN": tag, "week_year":active_week_div.text.strip()})
        dfs.append(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

And in the end, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all the DataFrames:

```
pd.concat(dfs).to_csv("top60.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Output (as DataFrame):

```
               Author                               Title Hebban_link                ISBN      week_year
0      Dirk de Wachter                      Vertroostingen        None  ISBN 9789026346897  week 1 - 2023
1      Charlotte Labee                  Overprikkeld brein        None  ISBN 9789026346897  week 1 - 2023
2   Israel van Dorsten                   Wij waren, ik ben        None  ISBN 9789026346897  week 1 - 2023
3          Delia Owens  Daar waar de rivierkreeften zingen        None  ISBN 9789026346897  week 1 - 2023
4                Kluun             Help, ik heb een puber!        None  ISBN 9789026346897  week 1 - 2023
..                 ...                                 ...         ...                 ...            ...
55         Raynor Winn                          Landlijnen        None  ISBN 9789043924009  week 4 - 2023
56        Michael Ende            Momo en de tijdspaarders        None  ISBN 9789043924009  week 4 - 2023
57    Arjen van Veelen                           Rotterdam        None  ISBN 9789043924009  week 4 - 2023
58        Jutta Chorus                     Alma's dochters        None  ISBN 9789043924009  week 4 - 2023
59        Jamie Oliver                  Jamie Oliver - EEN        None  ISBN 9789043924009  week 4 - 2023

[240 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: This makes sense yet when trying to place this in the code it still gives the same week times four and it freezes when trying to save to CSV. Would you mind checking if I placed this correctly in my OG code?

Comment: @jsb92 you also have an incorrect indentation for the DataFrame creation, do it once per URL, not once per book (see update, I tested my modifications and this gives a seemingly correct output)